# Possible with one MySQL query? "column contains any of the array's values"

Tags: mysql, arrays, contains

Basically I want to check whether a mysql text column, which contains comma-separated values, contains any of the values contained in an array. I know this can be done with a loop and multiple queries, but I was hoping for a single query. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a solution like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  str RLIKE
  CONCAT('[[:<:]]', REPLACE('values,in,the,array', ',', '[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]'), '[[:>:]]')
```

this will make the following string:

```
'values,in,the,array'
```

like this:

```
[[:<:]]values[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]in[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]the[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]array[[:>:]]
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are word boundaries so it will match only whole words, and | is an OR so it will match any of the words. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39ba97/1).

Comment: This is a smart method, which saves me from my day. Have to say again: NEVER use string instead of foreign keys!!! You will feel the pain one day!!!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
... WHERE my_column LIKE '%first_array_value%' OR my_column LIKE '%second_array_value%'
```

It will work but very bad because of performance. There is also another way

```
... WHERE MATCH (my_column) AGAINST ('first_array_value second_array_value')
```

but the best way is to change data structure if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE (my_column LIKE '%,0,%' OR my_column LIKE '%,1,%');`

or

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE (my_column REGEXP LIKE '.*,[0-1],.*');`